# Ionic tab page DOM wont display array items iusing *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, angular10

I am trying to implement Ionic tabs in an Ionic/Angular application.  However, when I try to display a string array in the tab page view using `*ngFor` it does not work. I have a button on the page that when clicked calls a function in the angular component for the page.  This populates a string array which is used to populate a list.

I have tested the button click and can confirm that the method is called and will log the data to the console using `console.log()`, so the issue is related to getting view to update.  The issue also appears to be specific to tab pages, as when I put the functionality elsewhere, for example, the header, it works without any issues.

home.page.html

```
<div id="container">    
    <ion-button (click)="getUsers()">Get Users</ion-button>    
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth-service.component';
import { ProjectService } from '../core/project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  users: string[];

  constructor(){}

  getUsers() {    

    this.users = ["user 1", "user 2", "user 3"]
    console.log(this.users);
    return this.users;
  }  

}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Check this link its working fine "https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-wkwmn6?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts"